# Javascript method definition inconsistency

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript Object with multiple methods. However i notice some inconsistency about the way the methods are defined.

Here is the object:

```
function MenuObject(containerId, skin) {

    this.id = containerId;
    this.something = something2;
    .
    .
    .
    this.anotherThing = anotherThing2;      

    this.setSkin = function(skin) { //We have a function here

        //body...
    {


}


MenuObject.prototype.getTopLevelPolygon = function() //Another function.
{
   var p = this.something3;

   //Method body goes here...
}
```

Some of the functions are defined like **this.functionName = function()**, others like **MenuObject.prototype.functionName = function()**

I am just wondering why are not all the functions that belong to the MenuObject defined as MenuObject.prototype.functionName  = function() ?

Comment: So the *real* question is "Why are methods added to .prototype?" or, maybe, "What is the 'prototype' property?" or .. Hint: search for "javascript prototype".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not using private instance variables, it is generally more efficient to define methods using the prototype because they are assigned to the new object in one fell swoop by the javascript internals (via the prototype) rather than assigned individually one at a time in your own code.

And, good coding practice would say that you should not use a mix of methods unless there is a specific reason for doing so (and this code doesn't indicate any particular reason for using the mix).

There are reasons for assigning methods in the constructor when you want them to have access to a private instance variable:

```
function MenuObject(containerId, skin) {

    var myPrivateVariable = 0;

    this.setSkin = function(skin) {
        // method can access myPrivateVariable here, 
        //    but a method put on the prototype cannot access it
    }
}
```

You can read more about private instance variables here: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: @JoroSeksa - see my latest edit.  It has a private instance variable.  See here for a more complete writeup: http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, the short answer is that items assigned with `this.functionName = function()` in the constructor are created on demand, while the ones created with `prototype` are more like static functions in that they exist outside of an instance of the "function" and are built upon program execution, as opposed to when instantiated. The inconsistencies are either intentional or a product of junior level programming (probably the earlier).

Edit:

By the way, there is even more to it than that, but the details go on and on, one thing just came to mind, it also allows you to have "private" functions inside the "class" if you will let me call it that. You can also define the prototype object in this way:

```
SomeFunction.prototype = {
     SomeFn1:function(){},
     SomeFn2:function(){},
     SomeFn3:function(){} // etc etc
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is when do you want to add the public functions to the object.

The `this.functionName = function()` method requires you to define all your object functions at the time of declaring the object `function MenuObject(containerId, skin) { ... };`.

The `MenuObject.prototype.functionName = function()` method allows you to **add additional** functions to the object *after having declared the object earlier*. So kind of like adding *plugins* or *augmenting* the object for different situations.

Answer (score 1):

Defining methods inside the constructor (this.method = fun..) can use "private" data via the use of closure. Also, methods inside the constructor are created everytime the the constructor is invoked. If you do not use 'new' when invoking the constructor, 'this' usually is attached to the global window object, and so can lead to very confusing and misunderstood bugs.

Defining methods outside of the constructor (MenuObj.prototype.method = fun..) can be overwritten later in the code at any time, while defining inside the constructor always takes precedence, and can't be overwritten by prototype modifications. Editing the prototype affects the prototype chain, and can lead to very confusing and misunderstood bugs.

I suggest reading Douglas Crockford's books or going to his website http://www.crockford.com/ and looking at the videos and essays on JavaScript.